# 日本人は「面白い」と聞いて何を感じますか？

Tags: word-choice, words

I am still a beginner at japanese and I have the strong feeling my title is incorrectly translated so here it is again in english:

*What is the "feeling" a japanese person gets upon hearing the word 面白い.*

To clarify: omoshiroi was one of the first japanese words I learned, and back then I was told it means "funny". Later "interesting" appended the list, and I never really understood the core of that word.

Lets say I want to express: "I think japanese is a very interesting language."

And I translate it to: 日本語が面白いと思います。

To me, the english word "interesting" feels very "serious", but the translations for 面白い don't suggest that very much. Jisho.org translates it to "interesting/amusing".

So, in that example sentence, did I rather say "I think japanese is interesting" ( in all seriousness ) or "I think japanese is a tad funny" ?
If its the latter, which word is used to express "interesting" in all seriousness ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I hear:

> 「面白いマンガ」
>   「面白い冗談・ジョーク」 「面白いことを言う」
>   「面白い芸人」「面白い顔」「面白い服装」

I would normally think the 面白い is used as "funny", "comical", "makes you laugh", or maybe "queer", etc.

When I hear:

> 「このゲーム/本/映画、面白かったよ。」
>   「(テレビで)今日、何か面白い番組やってる？」
>   「ディズニーランドとユニバーサルスタジオジャパンのどっちが面白い？」
>   「俺と勝負しろ！」--「面白い。相手になってやろう。」
>   「ドイツ語の勉強は面白いです。」「大学の勉強、面白い？」
>   「だんだん仕事が面白くなってきた。」

I would normally think the 面白い is used as "interesting", "exciting", "fun", "enjoyable", "rewarding / worthwhile", "you like it", etc.

So I would say:

> 日本語は面白いと思います。

to mean "I think the Japanese language is interesting." I wouldn't think you meant "I think the Japanese language is funny" if I heard you say this.

If I heard you say:

> 日本文化は面白いと思います。

I would think you meant "Japanese culture is interesting/intriguing". But if I heard you say:

> 日本人は面白いと思います。

I might think you probably meant "Japanese people are funny." (or maybe "Japanese people are interesting/fun." depending on the context.)

Answer (score 0):

What is the "feeling" a Japanese person gets upon hearing the word 面白い -> 日本人が「面白い」という言葉を聞いて得る"感覚"は何ですか？

I think Japanese is a very interesting language. -> 日本語 が/は 興{きょう}味{み}深{ぶか}い言語であると私は 思います/考えます。

FYI, Oxford English Dictionary says "interesting = arousing curiosity or interest; holding or catching the attention."

*** added ***

面白い can mean "interesting", but my impression is that it primarily means something is "funny."

Comment: What is the reason for downvote ?

Comment: @Slyps: <What is the reason for downvote ?> I really would like to know, too.