# 読解問題、「パソコンの向きに上下があるみたいで面白いですね」とはどういう意味ですか？

Tags: reading-comprehension

企業のIT部門の新人さん向けのセミナーでの会話ですが、

> 講師：古い時代のWindowsパソコンでは、ノースブリッジ（Northbridge）とサウスブリッジ（Southbridge）という2つのICがあります。
>
> 受講者：ノース（北）とサウス（南）って、地図みたいですね。
>
> 講師：地図では北が上で南が下であるように、回路図ではノースブリッジが上でサウスブリッジが下に示されます。
>
> 受講者：パソコンの向きに上下があるみたいで面白いですね！

最後の受講者からの話はどういう意味ですか？

パソコンはもともと向き（方向？）がないものだと思いますが、どうして上下が指されると（或いはそのICによって、上下が区別できると）、面白くなりますか？

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25641/5010 Here, nothing is funny, and 面白いですね just means "sounds interesting".

Comment: Incidentally, what is the right reading for 上下 here? I see うえした、しょうか、じょうげ, ...

Answer (score 1):

IT達人ではないけど、答えてみます。講師の話によって、回路図の描き方は地図の描き方と同じで、受講者は面白いと言ったみたいです。

地図を作成するとき、北にあるのは上に書かれ、南にあるのは下に書かれます。ノースブリッジは名前が「ノース」を含めて、北にあると思われてます。なので、回路図を作ると、ノースブリッジは「ノース」（北、だから上）に置かれ、サウスブリッジは地図のように下に置かれます。それが受講者の面白い点かもしれません。

その「面白い」は、回路図は地図のようで面白いのかもしれません。

Comment: 〜は上**に**書かれ、〜は下**に**書かれます for the same reason I explained in my answer to your recent question, if you don’t mind me correcting.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate these kind of corrections! They really do help me learn. Edited my answer.